# what does numpy if the value in an array exceeds int8

Tags: python, floating-point, uint8t

Consider the following piece of code:

```
test = np.ones((200,200))
test = test*20000
test_int8 = test.astype(np.int8)
```

When I implement this, I get that `test_int8` is filled with 32, why? and in general, if there's an array whose values exceed the maximum value that dtype I am converting into accepts, how does python handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`20000` in 32-bit binary is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 1110 0010 0000`.

As you can see, the last eight bits are `0010 0000`, which is `32`.

If you cast an int with a higher number of bits to a lower number, the top bits are just cut off (you could say it almost is... A stack overflow? (not quite by the way)).

Comment: how can I have python assign the highest possible if the value in the array exceed int8?

Comment: Use something like: `test_int8 = np.where(test > 255, 255, test_int8)'
Check the docs on `numpy.where` if you want to learn what it actually does. Be sure to take your time to understand!